# Store and retrieve an object of some typeclass - is it possible? If yes, how?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose I have some typeclass `Foo` and some data type `FooInst` that is instance of `Foo`:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> String

data FooInst = FooInst String

instance Foo FooInst where
    foo (FooInst s) = s
```

Now, I would like to define a data type that stores an object whose type is in the `Foo` typeclass and be able to extract that object from inside that data type and use it.

The only way I found is to use GADTs and Rank2Types language extensions and define the data type like this:

```
data Container where
  Container :: { content :: Foo a => a } -> Container
```

However, the problem is, that I cannot use the `content` selector to get the content out of the Container:

```
cont :: Container
cont = Container{content = FooInst "foo"}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let fi = content cont
  putStrLn $ foo fi
```

results to a compile error

```
Cannot use record selector ‘content’ as a function due to escaped type variables
Probable fix: use pattern-matching syntax instead
```

but when I modify the `let ...` line to

```
let Conainer fi = cont
```

I get a rather funny error

```
My brain just exploded
I can't handle pattern bindings for existential or GADT data constructors.
Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
```

And if I try to, again, modify the `let ...` line to use case-expression

```
let fi = case cont of
           Container x -> x
```

I get a a different error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘t’ with actual type ‘a’
  because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a pattern with constructor
    Container :: forall a. (Foo a => a) -> Container,
  in a case alternative
  at test.hs:23:14-24
```

So, **how can I store a typeclassed thing and retrieve it back?**

Comment: Section 4 [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) has a nice example of storing multiple items which have showable instances

Comment: Be careful not to fall into this known antipattern: https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Comment: @pdexter As far as I understand what you recommended me, my definition of ``Container`` is effectively equivalent to that of ``Showable``, except for the record syntax. Is it the record syntax then what makes it different for me? I find it weird that just a different syntax changes the semantics too...

Comment: You're using GADTs while the example is not. That's just one difference I spot at first glance. So it's not just different syntax but a different theory.

Comment: @pdexter The example shows at its very end that it can be equivalently expressed using GADTs. But behzad.nouri's answer more or less explains the difference. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6):

With:

```
data Container where
    Container :: {content :: Foo a => a} -> Container
```

the type class constraint *is not even enforced*. That is

```
void :: Container
void = Container {content = 42 :: Int}
```

type checks even though `42 :: Int` is *not* an instance of `Foo`.

But if you change to:

```
data Container where
    Container :: Foo a => {content :: a} -> Container
```

1. you no longer need `Rank2Types` language extension.
2. the type class constraint is enforced; therefore above `void` example will no longer type check.
3. further, you may invoke `foo` (or any other function with signature `Foo a => a -> ...`) on the content with pattern matching:

   ```
   case cont of Container {content = a} -> foo a
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  case cont of
    Container fi -> putStrLn $ foo fi
```

You need to encapsulate your use of the existentially-typed field `fi` in an expression whose type does not depend on the type of `fi`; here `putStrLn $ foo fi` which has type `IO ()`.

This example is quite useless since the only thing you can do to the `content` field of a `Container` is call `foo` on it, so you might as well just call `foo` before constructing the container and give the field type `String`. But it's more interesting if `Foo` has operations with types like `a -> a -> a`, or `Container` has multiple fields with types that involve the same existentially quantified variable, etc.

Comment: Your code didn't work for me, I got error ``No instance for (Foo a) arising from a use of ‘foo’  Possible fix: add (Foo a) to the context of the data constructor ‘Container’``.

Comment: I didn't notice that you also defined `Container` wrong. behzad.nouri's answer has what you meant.